# AS3: Audio activity level of a NetStream

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm pulling my hair out (once again), trying to find a way to read the activity level of audio of a NetStream, similar to how you can do it with a Microphone. I'd hate to have to let each client send it's activitylevel through SharedObjects or the like, which right seems to be the only way to actually get it to work.

Thanks so much in advance!

-Dave

Comment: Maybe if you explain why you want to do this there may be more input for a workaround.

Comment: I need to be able to get the activity level like I can with a local Microphone, so I can visualize that user's volume level. Hope that explains!

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, too. I somehow didn't receive an email notification from StackOverflow :)

Comment: Why is there a bounty on this? If hhelms didn't nail it, then there is no answer.

Comment: At first no-one seem to knew the answer, so I added an extra incentive. I wonder why I have to explain this to you, though. Very little people even knew that what hhelms mentioned was possible, so blindly assuming it's the only way (or, as you put it, there 'is no answer') is awfully silly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In AS3 the Netstream Object has a property called .info. This holds the object NetStreamInfo. NetstreamInfo will give you all sorts of metrics. Among them is the property 'audioBytesPerSecond' which will give you an indication of the audio activity at a certain point in time. Requesting the NetStreamInfo for  the incoming stream will provide you with the data from the client. Requesting the NetStreamInfo for the outgoing stream will provide you data from your own cam and mic activity. More detail on the NetStreamInfo object can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/NetStreamInfo.html

Comment: This seems plausible. I bow to your Netstream knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems like the best thing to do for now. My apologies for missing out on giving you my own bounty, I was out of the office all day yesterday and came in this morning only to realize the deadline was sometime this night (Different timezones).

Thanks again!

Comment: No problem and thanks very much. I use this myself regularly. NetStreamInfo does not have any events like the mic activity event, but polling it a couple of times a second works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

NetStreamInfo.audioBytesPerSecond is unreliable. 
Being a per second average, it takes one extra second before you could detect the lack of sound.

You should instead use NetStreamInfo.audioByteCount. As from Adobe documentation:

*Specifies the total number of audio bytes that have arrived in the queue, regardless of how many have been played or flushed. You can use this value to calculate the incoming audio data rate, using the metric of your choice, by creating a timer and calculating the difference in values in successive timer calls.*

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the only way to do it. NetStream is a pretty generic object by design. The best site to ask a question like this might be on [FlashComGuru.com](http://flashcomguru.com/) where a lot of NetStream/FMS guys hang out.

Comment: Seems like a lot of objects in Flex are generic by design, I keep running into these limitations. I highly doubt I'm the only one who wants something like this.. Too bad. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Flex examples that displays an eq bar.

the code uses two objects

SoundTransform and flash.media.SoundChannel

it functions by dispatching a custom event that has a property which is the SoundChannel object containing the EQ of the playing audio stream.

not sure exactly how the doe works cause it's bundled up in flex, or how to get from the NetStream to the audio based SoundChannel.

The example is in chapter 15 "Building your own components" of the book "Flex 3 component solutions" by jack herrington. published by friends of ed (the pink spine books).

hope that helps.