# Is there any way to get volume level of netStream in Actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, netstream

I want to get the activity level of audio of a NetStream, similar to how you can do it with a Microphone.
In this article,
[AS3: Audio activity level of a NetStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442913/as3-audio-activity-level-of-a-netstream)
NetStreamInfo.audioBytesPerSecond is said to be the solution.
However, audioBytesPerSecond indicates how many data volume the stream have.
It does not get volume level of the stream.
It is not the same as microphone.activityLevel.

Is there any way to get volume level of netStream?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** it seems that you're looking for sound spectrum, not volume level. `SoundMixer` class a method called `computeSpectrum`, which fills an instance of `ByteArray` with raw sound data of a single moment.
You can read about `SoundMixer` more here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/media/SoundMixer.html
And here's a an example with source code that could aid you in achieving your goal: http://www.todaycreate.com/2007/02/18/actionscript-3-spectrum-analyzer

`NetStream` has `soundTransform` property which references to a `SoundTransform` object which in turn has `volume` property for getting and setting volume level. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I want to make this kind of volume meter.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iixBz5JK6s4

I think SoundTransform.volume is the output volume level which users set.
It will not change until user change its setting.
(If I set it as 1, I get 1 whenever I do getVolume)

Microphone.activityLevel would change depend on its input.
I want to get microphone activity level of the streaming source client.

Comment: Thanks again. It seems that SoundMixer class cannot be used for dynamic sound such as streaming.

Comment: But thank you very much for your suggestion. Data I want to get is exactly what SoundMixer.computeSpectrum gives.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the way to get SoundMixer.computeSpectrum of streaming movie.
I made it with Wowza Media Server and flash 10.1.
How to do;
http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?7055-Example-of-how-to-use-ComputeSpectrum-with-Wowza-Pro

The following line was crutial(on page 2)
ns.bufferTime = 3;